# SPSS: How to code a macro (loop etc.) that uses multiple "Computes" (Char.Substr and Char.Index) for multiple variables. (5-6 outputs per Var(29))

Tags: spss

My data includes oddly entered data. I need to break up a string that may either consist of a 1-2 digit age, or two ages separated by either a comma or a period. The comma indicates ongoing exposure and a period represents a separate incident.

I have the base code to apply to a single variable, but I just invest 2-3 hours attempting to automate so we can change it in a single line rather than code it 29 times separately. Thought this would be easy, but I've been messing around with Loops and "!" for way too long at this point. Any guidance would be appreciated.

If it helps, the existing code is below.

```
**Split Ages and Determine Continuous or Intermittent.
*ID position of comma and period.
Compute Period = CHAR.INDEX (Var, ".").
Execute. 

Compute Comma = CHAR.INDEX (Var, ",").
Execute.  

*Seperate ages into seperate variables.
STRING Age1(A2)    Age2(A2).

DO IF (Comma = 2 or Period=2).
COMPUTE Age1 = CHAR.SUBSTR (Var,1,1).
COMPUTE Age2 = CHAR.SUBSTR (Var,3).

ELSE IF (Comma = 3  or Period=3).
COMPUTE Age1 = CHAR.SUBSTR (Var,1,2).
COMPUTE Age2 = CHAR.SUBSTR (Var,4).

ELSE IF (Comma = 0 and Period = .00).
COMPUTE Age1 = Var.
END IF.

*Convert String to Numeric.
alter type Age1(f2).
alter type Age2(f2).
execute.

*Cont or Int.
DO IF (Period >0).
Compute Multiple = 1.
END IF.

DO IF (Comma >0).
Compute Duration = Age2 - Age1.
END IF. 


EXECUTE.
```

Comment: That is not that bad - you can eliminate all of those execute statements, and use scratch variables. There is not much to gain from loops or do repeat. If you wanted to make a macro all you need to do is pass in at max three parameters -- the string you want to parse and the two output variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way to do this is with a snippet of Python code and the SPSSINC TRANS extension command, which is normally installed with Statistics.

Some data:
    data list list /age(a5).
    begin data
    21
    22,23
    22.23
    end data.

Use the extension command to create two new variables.  The second will be blank if there no separator.  The code splits the string into parts wherever a period or comma is found.  Note that different types of quote characters are used in the formula.

```
spssinc trans result=part1 part2 type=2
/formula "re.split('[.,]',age)".
```

If you want to learn more about using Python with Statistics, download the Programming and Data Management book from the SPSS Community website.
https://developer.ibm.com/predictiveanalytics/docs/spss-statistics/programming-and-data-management-book/

Answer (score 0):

What I posted yesterday shows how to easily split a single variable.  Here is a way to extend this to split an entire list of variables in one pass.  I'll illustrate with just two age variables.

First, you define a splitting function that can loop over multiple variables.

```
begin program.
import re
def splitter(*x):
    # x is a list of values to split
    result = []
    for item in x:
        splits =  re.split("[.,]", item)
        if len(splits) == 1:
            splits.append("")
        result.extend(splits)
    return(result)
end program.
```

Then you specify the SPSSINC TRANS command with all the age variables.  In the example, I use TO to refer to a list of contiguous variables, but you could alternatively list all the individual variable names.

The result variable list uses TO and specifies twice as many variables as the input.  Again, you could list specific variable names if desired.

```
spssinc trans result=part1 to part4 type=2
/variables age to age2
/formula "splitter(<>)".
```

The angle brackets here indicate that all the variables listed or implied on the variables subcommand should be passed as arguments.

p.s.  If you want the result variables to be numeric instead of strings, you can change the type from 2 to 0.  That will make the second variable in a pair system missing if there was no period or comma in its input.